# How to drag images / objects within Canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, 3d, 2d

1) On Canvas I am drawing SVG file (awesome_tiger.svg) with drawSvg (canvg).

2) On that SVG file I am plotting images**(green1.png and pink.png)** whose co-ordinates are getting from JSON.

```
var dataJSON = data || [];
var dataJSON2 = data2 || [];
```

3) So on I am able to pan complete drawing which I am drawing with **draw1(scaleValue).**

4) When I click on green.png and pink.png then their respective tooltip is able to view that is done in **tooltipFunc** function.

**5) What I want to do is, when click on green.png / pink.png and drag it I should be able to drag those images only not the Svg file. If I click on svg file and drag it then normal pan should work which is working by default.**

**Can Anyone please help?**

**"Others reference for my problem:"** Content of this topic mention below, I got this on stackoverflow link. With the help of this can anyone help me with my project requirement problem?

**Following is my source code :**

JSON Data :

```
data = [  
        {   "id" :["first"],        
            "x": ["195"],
            "y": ["150"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 1"]

        },  
        {
            "id" :["second"],
            "x": ["255"],
            "y": ["180"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 2"]      
        },
        {
            "id" :["third"],
            "x": ["200"],
            "y": ["240"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 3"]      
        }       

    ];

data2 = [  
        {   "id" :["first2"],       
            "x": ["225"],
            "y": ["150"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 21"]

        },  
        {
            "id" :["second2"],
            "x": ["275"],
            "y": ["180"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 22"]     
        },
        {
            "id" :["third3"],
            "x": ["300"],
            "y": ["240"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 23"]     
        }       

    ];


Javascript Code:        

var dataJSON = data || [];
var dataJSON2 = data2 || [];
window.onload = function(){ 
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');      
    var tooltip = null,
            timer;

    //svg file and png files are collected in files.
    var files = ["/static/images/awesome_tiger.svg", "/static/images/green1.png", "/static/images/pink.png"],
    images = [],
    numOfFiles = files.length,
    count = numOfFiles;

    /// function to load all images in one go
    function loadImages() {
        /// go through array of file names
        for(var i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++) {
            /// create an image element
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            /// use common loader as we need to count files
            img.onload = imageLoaded;

            //img.onerror = ... handle errors
            img.src = files[i];                 
            /// push image onto array in the same order as file names
            images.push(img);

        }
    }
    loadImages();
    function imageLoaded(e) {
        /// for each successful load we count down
        count--;            
        if (count === 1)            
        start(); //start when nothing more to count
    }
    function start() {      
        context.drawSvg(files[0], 0, 0, 400*scaleValue, 400*scaleValue);    

       for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON[i]; i++) {         
           /// as we know the alpha ball has index 1 we use that here for images
           context.drawImage(images[1], pos.x, pos.y, 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);
       }
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON2[i]; i++) {             
           context.drawImage(images[2], pos.x, pos.y, 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);
       }
    }
    //Drawing the svg file with drawSvg and images with drawImage(dataJSON and dataJSON2 are JSON through with will get the x an y co-ordinates for those images to draw)

    function draw1(scaleValue){             
        context.save();     
        context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)   
        context.globalAlpha = 0.5;                      
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   
        context.restore();          
        context.save(); 
        context.drawSvg(files[0], 0, 0, 400*scaleValue, 400*scaleValue)
        context.scale(scaleValue, scaleValue);
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON[i]; i++) {
               /// as we know the alpha ball has index 1 we use that here for images
               context.drawImage(images[1], pos.x, pos.y, 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);
           }    
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON2[i]; i++) {
               /// as we know the alpha ball has index 1 we use that here for images
               context.drawImage(images[2], pos.x, pos.y, 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);
           }
        context.restore();
    }; 

//Code for Zoom In and Zoom Out
    var scaleValue = 1;
    var scaleMultiplier = 0.8;
    draw1(scaleValue);
    var startDragOffset = {};
    var mouseDown = false;          
    // add button event listeners
    document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function(){           
        scaleValue /= scaleMultiplier;                          
        draw1(scaleValue);              
    }, false);
     document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function(){
        scaleValue *= scaleMultiplier;              
        draw1(scaleValue);      
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("original_size").addEventListener("click", function(){
        scaleValue = 1;                 
        draw1(scaleValue);  
    }, false);

    //Code for panning on canvas

    var isDown = false;
    var startCoords = [];
    var transX, transY;
    var last = [0, 0];

    canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
        clearTooltip();
        isDown = true;          
        startCoords = [
            e.offsetX - last[0],
            e.offsetY - last[1]
       ];
    };

    canvas.onmouseup  = function(e){        
        isDown = false;         
        last = [
            e.offsetX - startCoords[0], // set last coordinates
            e.offsetY - startCoords[1]
        ];
    };

    canvas.onmousemove = function(e){   
            var x = e.offsetX;              
            var y = e.offsetY;

            transX = parseInt(parseInt(x) - parseInt(startCoords[0]));
            transY = parseInt(parseInt(y) - parseInt(startCoords[1]));

            if(!isDown) return; 
            context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, transX, transY);                                   
            draw1(scaleValue);  
    }


    canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {          
        var x = e.offsetX;              
        var y = e.offsetY;

        transX = parseInt(parseInt(x) - parseInt(startCoords[0]));
        transY = parseInt(parseInt(y) - parseInt(startCoords[1]));

        tooltipFunc(e, transX, transY); 

    }, false);


    //tooptip function
    function tooltipFunc(e, transX, transY){
        //document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        var translationX, translationY;
        var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
                    x = e.clientX - r.left,
                    y = e.clientY - r.top,
                    i = 0,
                    r,
                    inTooltip = false;

        if((typeof startCoords[0] == 'undefined' || startCoords[0] === 'NaN') && (typeof startCoords[1] === 'undefined' || startCoords[1] === 'NaN')){  
            console.log('if');
                for (; r = dataJSON[i]; i++) {              
                    if (x >= parseInt(dataJSON[i].x[0] * scaleValue) + parseInt(scaleValue) && x <= parseInt(dataJSON[i].x[0] * scaleValue) + parseInt(20/scaleValue) && y >= parseInt(dataJSON[i].y[0] * scaleValue) && y <= parseInt(dataJSON[i].y[0] * scaleValue) + parseInt(20/scaleValue)) {
                        //clearTooltip();
                        showTooltip(e.clientX, e.clientY, i);
                        inTooltip = true;
                    }
                }
        }
        else {
            console.log('else');                                    
        for (var i = 0; r = dataJSON[i]; i++) { 
                    console.log('else for');                    
                    if(x >= parseInt(parseInt(dataJSON[i].x[0] * scaleValue) + parseInt(scaleValue) + parseInt(transX)) && x <= parseInt(parseInt(dataJSON[i].x[0] * scaleValue) + parseInt(scaleValue) + parseInt(transX) + parseInt(20)) && y >= parseInt(parseInt(dataJSON[i].y[0] * scaleValue) + parseInt(scaleValue) + parseInt(transY)) && y <= parseInt(parseInt(dataJSON[i].y[0] * scaleValue) + parseInt(scaleValue) + parseInt(transY) + parseInt(20))) {                        
                        clearTooltip();                                             
                        showTooltip(e.clientX, e.clientY, i);
                        inTooltip = true;
                    }
            }
            for (var i = 0; r = dataJSON2[i]; i++) {    
                    console.log('else for');                    
                    if(x >= parseInt(parseInt(dataJSON2[i].x[0] * scaleValue) + parseInt(scaleValue) + parseInt(transX)) && x <= parseInt(parseInt(dataJSON2[i].x[0] * scaleValue) + parseInt(scaleValue) + parseInt(transX) + parseInt(20)) && y >= parseInt(parseInt(dataJSON2[i].y[0] * scaleValue) + parseInt(scaleValue) + parseInt(transY)) && y <= parseInt(parseInt(dataJSON2[i].y[0] * scaleValue) + parseInt(scaleValue) + parseInt(transY) + parseInt(20))) {                        
                        clearTooltip();                         
                        showTooltip2(e.clientX, e.clientY, i);
                        inTooltip = true;
                    }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Others reference for my problem:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="c" width = "500" height = "500" ></canvas>    

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = $("#c");
var c = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

//var path = "http://wonderfl.net/images/icon/e/ec/ec3c/ec3c37ba9594a7b47f1126b2561efd35df2251bfm";
var path = "blue.jpg";
var path2 = "purple.jpg";
var image1 = new DragImage(path, 200, 100);
var image2 = new DragImage(path2, 300, 100);

var loop = setInterval(function() {

    c.fillStyle = "gray";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    image1.update();
    image2.update();
}, 30);

var mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;
var mousePressed = false;
var dragging = false;
canvas.mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = e.offsetX;
    mouseY = e.offsetY;
})

$(document).mousedown(function() {
    mousePressed = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
    mousePressed = false;
    dragging = false;
});

function DragImage(src, x, y) {
    var that = this;
    var startX = 0,
        startY = 0;
    var drag = false;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    this.update = function() {
        if (mousePressed ) {

                var left = that.x;
                var right = that.x + img.width;
                var top = that.y;
                var bottom = that.y + img.height;
                if (!drag) {
                    startX = mouseX - that.x;
                    startY = mouseY - that.y;
                }
                if (mouseX < right && mouseX > left && mouseY < bottom && mouseY > top) {
                    if (!dragging){
            dragging = true;
                        drag = true;
                    }

                }

        } else {

            drag = false;
        }
        if (drag) {
            that.x = mouseX - startX;
            that.y = mouseY - startY;
        }
        c.drawImage(img, that.x, that.y);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully I understand your question...!

**Here’s how to both pan a canvas and drag objects on the canvas**

This illustrates the canvas before any dragging or panning:

Notice the green rect is over the tiger's left eye.

[image]

This illustrates the canvas after the green rect has been dragged to the right eye:

[image]

This illustrates the canvas after panning.

Both the tiger and all rects will pan simultaneously.

[image]

Most of the important code is in the mousedown and mousemove event handlers

**On mousedown:**

- If the mouse is over 1+ colored-images, then drag the image(s).
- If the mouse is not over any colored-images, then pan the canvas.

Here is the mousedown code:

```
function handleMouseDown(e){

  // get mouse coordinates

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // set the starting drag position 
  // this is needed in mousemove to determine how far we have dragged
  lastX=mouseX;
  lastY=mouseY;

  // test if we're over any of the images
  // if yes, put those image(s) in an array called dragging
  dragging=imagesHitTests(mouseX,mouseY);

  // set the dragging flag
  isDown=true;

}
```

**On mousemove:**

- Determine if we’re dragging or panning.
- If the dragging[] array is not empty, we’re dragging.
- If the dragging[] array is empty, we’re panning.
- When dragging, change each dragged image’s XY by the amount we have dragged.
- When panning, change the tiger position by the amount we have dragged.

Here is the mousemove code:

```
function handleMouseMove(e){

  // if we're not dragging, exit
  if(!isDown){return;}

  //get mouse coordinates
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // calc how much the mouse has moved since we were last here
  var dx=mouseX-lastX;
  var dy=mouseY-lastY;

  // set the lastXY for next time we're here
  lastX=mouseX;
  lastY=mouseY;

  // handle drags/pans
  if(dragging.length>0){
      // we're dragging images
      // move all affected images by how much the mouse has moved
      for(var i=0;i<dragging.length;i++){
          img=images[dragging[i]];
          img.x+=dx;
          img.y+=dy;
      }
  }else{
      // we're panning the tiger
      // set the panXY by how much the mouse has moved
      panX+=dx;
      panY+=dy;
  }
  draw();
}
```

**And here is code to determine which color-images are under the mouse--and will be dragged.**

Any color-image under the mouse is added to an array called "dragging".

This dragging[] array is used in mousemove to drag the appropriate color-image(s).

```
  // create an array of any "hit" colored-images
  function imagesHitTests(x,y){
      // adjust for panning
      x-=panX;
      y-=panY;
      // create var to hold any hits
      var hits=[];
      // hit-test each image
      // add hits to hits[]
      for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
          var img=images[i];
          if(x>img.x && x<img.x+img.width && y>img.y && y<img.y+img.height){
              hits.push(i);
          }
      }
      return(hits);
  }
```

Here is complete code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/pbRq2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px;}
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeStyle="red";
    ctx.lineWidth=5;

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var lastX=0;
    var lastY=0;
    var panX=0;
    var panY=0;
    var dragging=[];
    var isDown=false;


    // create green & pink "images" (we just use rects instead of images)
    var images=[];
    images.push({x:200,y:150,width:25,height:25,color:"green"});
    images.push({x:80,y:235,width:25,height:25,color:"pink"});

    // load the tiger image
    var tiger=new Image();
    tiger.onload=function(){
        draw();
    }
    tiger.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/tiger.png";


    function draw(){

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        // draw tiger
        ctx.globalAlpha=0.25;
        ctx.drawImage(tiger,panX,panY,tiger.width,tiger.height);

        // draw color images
        ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
        for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            var img=images[i];
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(img.x+panX,img.y+panY,img.width,img.height);
            ctx.fillStyle=img.color;
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    // create an array of any "hit" colored-images
    function imagesHitTests(x,y){
        // adjust for panning
        x-=panX;
        y-=panY;
        // create var to hold any hits
        var hits=[];
        // hit-test each image
        // add hits to hits[]
        for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            var img=images[i];
            if(x>img.x && x<img.x+img.width && y>img.y && y<img.y+img.height){
                hits.push(i);
            }
        }
        return(hits);
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){

      // get mouse coordinates
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      // set the starting drag position
      lastX=mouseX;
      lastY=mouseY;
      // test if we're over any of the images
      dragging=imagesHitTests(mouseX,mouseY);
      // set the dragging flag
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      // clear the dragging flag
      isDown=false;
    }


    function handleMouseMove(e){

      // if we're not dragging, exit
      if(!isDown){return;}

      //get mouse coordinates
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // calc how much the mouse has moved since we were last here
      var dx=mouseX-lastX;
      var dy=mouseY-lastY;

      // set the lastXY for next time we're here
      lastX=mouseX;
      lastY=mouseY;

      // handle drags/pans
      if(dragging.length>0){
          // we're dragging images
          // move all affected images by how much the mouse has moved
          for(var i=0;i<dragging.length;i++){
              img=images[dragging[i]];
              img.x+=dx;
              img.y+=dy;
          }
      }else{
          // we're panning the tiger
          // set the panXY by how much the mouse has moved
          panX+=dx;
          panY+=dy;
      }
      draw();
    }

    // use jQuery to handle mouse events
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Let me implement this in my code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Implemented the above in my code. Now it is working. Thank you