# How to drag images / objects within Canvas after zooming / scaling them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, 3d, 2d

Following is my Complete code. Which is edited as per this link [How to drag images / objects within Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333936/how-to-drag-images-objects-within-canvas/18342255#18342255).

**Requirement :**

Basically what I am doing is, First I am drawing SVG file on canvas with drawSvg with the help of canvg.

On this file I am plotting images(green1.png and orange1.png) through JSON  which is present in markers.js.

**Scenario 1:**

If I pan without Zooming/scaling then able to drag those images(green1.png, orange1.png) and able to pan canvas properly.

But If I zoom after panning then images are not translating on proper position because of panX and panY points. But panX and panY are point we want for panning.

**Scenario 2:** :

If I scale/zoom first and then if I pan then images(orange1.png, green1.png) are changing their position and not able to drag images (orange1.png, green1.png).

**What can be done in these scenarios?**

HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>      
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            canvas {
                border:1px solid #000
            }
            .tooltip{
                *position:fixed;
                position:absolute;
                *background:#ff7;
                background:green;
                border:1px solid #000;
                padding:7px;
                font-family:sans-serif;
                font-size:12px;
            }
            .tooltip2  {
                *position:fixed;
                position:absolute;
                background:pink;
                border:1px solid #000;
                padding:7px;
                font-family:sans-serif;
                font-size:12px;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbcolor.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/StackBlur.js"></script>
    <script src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/canvg.js"></script>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="700" style="border: 1px solid;margin-top: 10px;"></canvas>
    <div id="buttonWrapper">
        <input type="button" id="plus" value="+">
        <input type="button" id="minus" value="-">
        <input type="button" id="original_size" value="100%">       
    </div>  
    <script src="/static/js/markers.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/draw.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

draw.js:

```
var dataJSON = data || [];
var dataJSON2 = data2 || [];
window.onload = function(){ 
  //$(function(){              
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");        

    var canvasOffset=$("#myCanvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var lastX=0;
    var lastY=0;
    var panX=0;
    var panY=0;
    var dragging=[];
    var dragging2=[];
    var isDown=false;

    function loadImages(sources, callback){
      var images = {};
      var loadImages = 0;
      var numImages = 0;
      //get num of sources
      for(var i in sources){            
        numImages++;
      }
      for(var i in sources){            
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].onload = function(){
          if(++loadImages >= numImages){
            callback(images);
          }
        };
        images[i].src = sources[i];            
      }
    }

    var sources = {orange : '/static/images/orange1.png', green : '/static/images/green1.png'};


    // load the tiger image
    var svgfiles = ["/static/images/awesome_tiger.svg"];
    /*var tiger=new Image();
    tiger.onload=function(){
      draw();
    }
     tiger.src="tiger.png";*/

    function draw(scaleValue){ 
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);    
      ctx.save();
      ctx.drawSvg(svgfiles[0],panX,panY,400*scaleValue, 400*scaleValue);         
      //ctx.drawImage(tiger,panX,panY,tiger.width,tiger.height);    
       //ctx.scale(scaleValue, scaleValue);
      loadImages(sources, function(images){     
        ctx.scale(scaleValue, scaleValue);
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON[i]; i++) {            
          ctx.drawImage(images.orange, parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) + parseInt(panX)), parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) + parseInt(panY)), 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);               
        }
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON2[i]; i++) {            
          ctx.drawImage(images.green, parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) + parseInt(panX)), parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) + parseInt(panY)), 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);             
        }
        ctx.restore();
      });

    };
    var scaleValue = 1;
    var scaleMultiplier = 0.8;
    draw(scaleValue);
    var startDragOffset = {};
    var mouseDown = false;          
    // add button event listeners
    document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function(){           
        scaleValue /= scaleMultiplier;  
        //checkboxZoomPan();            
        draw(scaleValue);               
    }, false);
     document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function(){
        scaleValue *= scaleMultiplier;
        //checkboxZoomPan();            
        draw(scaleValue);       
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("original_size").addEventListener("click", function(){
        scaleValue = 1;
        //checkboxZoomPan();            
        draw(scaleValue);   
    }, false);


    // create an array of any "hit" colored-images
    function imagesHitTests(x,y){   
      // adjust for panning
      x-=panX;
      y-=panY;
      // create var to hold any hits
      var hits=[];
      // hit-test each image
      // add hits to hits[]
      loadImages(sources, function(images){
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON[i]; i++) { 
          if(x >= parseInt(pos.x * scaleValue) && x <= parseInt((pos.x * scaleValue) + 20) && y >= parseInt(pos.y * scaleValue) && y <= parseInt((pos.y * scaleValue) + 20)){
            hits.push(i);           
          }              
        }            
      });          
      return(hits);
    }

    function imagesHitTests2(x,y){      
      // adjust for panning
      //x-=panX;
      //x = parseInt(x) - parseInt(panX);     
     // y-=panY;
     x-=panX;
     y-=panY;
      // create var to hold any hits
      var hits2=[];
      // hit-test each image
      // add hits to hits[]
      loadImages(sources, function(images){            
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON2[i]; i++) {          
          //if(x > pos.x && x < parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) + parseInt(20)) && y > pos.y && y < parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) + parseInt(20))){
          if(x >= parseInt(pos.x * scaleValue) && x <= parseInt((pos.x * scaleValue) + 20) && y >= parseInt(pos.y * scaleValue) && y <= parseInt((pos.y * scaleValue) + 20)){           
            hits2.push(i);          
          }              
        }            
      });          
      return(hits2);
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      // get mouse coordinates
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      // set the starting drag position
      lastX=mouseX;
      lastY=mouseY;
      // test if we're over any of the images
      dragging=imagesHitTests(mouseX,mouseY);
      dragging2=imagesHitTests2(mouseX,mouseY);
      // set the dragging flag    
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      // clear the dragging flag
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      // if we're not dragging, exit
      if(!isDown){
        return;
      }

      //get mouse coordinates
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // calc how much the mouse has moved since we were last here
      var dx=mouseX-lastX;
      var dy=mouseY-lastY;

      // set the lastXY for next time we're here
      lastX=mouseX;
      lastY=mouseY;

      // handle drags/pans
      if(dragging.length>0){      
        // we're dragging images
        // move all affected images by how much the mouse has moved            
        for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON[dragging[i]]; i++) {              
          pos.x = parseInt(pos.x) + parseInt(dx);
          pos.y = parseInt(pos.y) + parseInt(dy);              
        }
      }
      else if(dragging2.length>0){      
        for(var i = 0, pos1; pos1 = dataJSON2[dragging2[i]]; i++) {              
          pos1.x = parseInt(pos1.x) + parseInt(dx);              
          pos1.y = parseInt(pos1.y) + parseInt(dy);
        }            
      }
      else{
        // we're panning the tiger
        // set the panXY by how much the mouse has moved
        panX+=dx;
        panY+=dy;
      }
      draw(scaleValue);
    }


    // use jQuery to handle mouse events
    $("#myCanvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#myCanvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#myCanvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});

// }); // end $(function(){});
  }
```

markers.js:

```
data = [  
        {   "id" :["first"],        
            "x": ["195"],
            "y": ["150"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 1"]

        },  
        {
            "id" :["second"],
            "x": ["255"],
            "y": ["180"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 2"]      
        },
        {
            "id" :["third"],
            "x": ["200"],
            "y": ["240"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 3"]      
        }       

    ];

data2 = [  
        {   "id" :["first2"],       
            "x": ["225"],
            "y": ["150"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 21"]

        },  
        {
            "id" :["second2"],
            "x": ["275"],
            "y": ["180"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 22"]     
        },
        {
            "id" :["third3"],
            "x": ["300"],
            "y": ["240"],
            "tooltiptxt": ["Region 23"]     
        }       

    ];
```

Comment: positionX * xScale and positionY * yScale

Comment: @amorbytes : hey thank you. I tired same thing but scale value I was putting in parseInt that is why it was taking value 1 . Its working thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.)
positionX * xScale and positionY * yScale

2.)
try this code in draw function

```
ctx.drawImage(images.orange, parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) + parseInt(panX / scaleValue)), parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) + parseInt(panY / scaleValue)), 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);
```

Comment: One more query with this I am having is, With above answer I am able to drag images after Scaling/Zooming. But when I pan the Svg file then I am not able to drag those images. Which translate points should I add in imagesHitTests functions so that I am able to drag images after panning also?

Comment: @eegloo could you please create one jsfiddle for your code. where I can see live demo. it might helps me to figure out your problem.

Comment: I am not able to give reference of JavaScript files in jsfiddle. Links are mention there which need to use. http://jsfiddle.net/VSK9K/5/

Comment: just shooting in the blank. could you try
`panX + (positionX * xScale)` and
`panY + (positionY * yScale)`

Comment: one more suggestion position means (x,y) and scale values like (scaleX,scaleY) also distance value like(dx,dy) on that value try to avoid using parseINT it may affects to your accuracy.

Comment: parseInt(panX + (pos.x * scaleValue)) this give proper calculation but still not working after panning.

Comment: Any other option please?

Comment: If I replace this :

x-=panX;

y-=panY;

With :

x-=panX * scaleValue;

y-=panY * scaleValue;

Then after zoom if I pan the canvas then able to drag images.
But While panning the canvas , images drawn on it are getting translate(Changing their position).

Comment: could you please edit your question by pasting your complete source code HTML,js and css if any ?.

Comment: I have updated my question with my latest source code. Can you please take a look?

Comment: try this code in draw function `ctx.drawImage(images.orange,`
`parseInt(parseInt(pos.x) + parseInt(panX / scaleValue)), parseInt(parseInt(pos.y) + parseInt(panY / scaleValue))`